# Mouse pointer position when a label is activated

Tags: c++, qt, events, mouse

When an object of QLabel sub class is actived, how can one find if the mouse pointer is on the label and get its position if it is?

QWidegt::event() can check the event type of QEvent::WindowActivate, but it provides no information about mouse pointer position.

## UPDATE

According to comment by @Mathias Schmid , I create the following code. It verifies itself that both focusInEvent and focusOutEvent can happen. However, I still cannot get the mouse pointer position. Maybe I am missing the part of "bind enable/disable of mouse tracking to focus in and out events", or something else.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtCore>

class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    MyLabel(QWidget*parent = nullptr) : QLabel(parent)
    {
        setMouseTracking(true);
        setFocusPolicy(Qt::FocusPolicy::StrongFocus);
    }

protected:
    virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *ev) override
    {
        (void)ev;
        this->setText(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
    virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *ev) override
    {
        (void)ev;
        this->setText(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }

    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override
    {
        this->setText(QString::number(ev->pos().x()) +", " +QString::number(ev->pos().y()));

        QLabel::mouseMoveEvent(ev);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyLabel w;
    w.setFixedSize(400, 300);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

## Update 2: solution

Thanks to @Mathias Schmid, the final solution is to use static function QCursor::pos() in focusInEvent().

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCursor>

class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    MyLabel(QWidget*parent = nullptr) : QLabel(parent)
    {
        setMouseTracking(true);
        setFocusPolicy(Qt::FocusPolicy::StrongFocus);
    }

protected:
    virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *ev) override
    {
        (void)ev;
        QPoint pos = QCursor::pos();
        QString msg = QString(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) + ": \n" +  QString::number(pos.x()) + ", " + QString::number(pos.y());
        QPoint posLocal = this->mapFromGlobal(pos);
        if(this->rect().contains(posLocal))
            msg += "\nLocal pos: " + QString::number(posLocal.x()) + ", " + QString::number(posLocal.y());

        this->setText(msg);

        QLabel::focusInEvent(ev);
    }
    virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *ev) override
    {
        (void)ev;
        this->setText(QString(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__));

        QLabel::focusOutEvent(ev);
    }

    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override
    {
        this->setText(QString::number(ev->pos().x()) +", " +QString::number(ev->pos().y()));

        QLabel::mouseMoveEvent(ev);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyLabel w;
    w.setFixedSize(450, 300);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You could activate mouse tracking via `setMouseTracking(true)` for your `QLabel` subclass and override `mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)` to get informed about mouse movement on your label widget and get mouse position. On top of that you could bind enable/disable of mouse tracking to focus in and out events. Therefore it's necessary to override `focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *ev)` and `focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *ev)` and set focus policy accordingly.

Comment: I used the source code you provided by update and it works. I can see the changing `x` and `y` position label text if i move the mouse on it. It also works without using/overriding the focus events.

Comment: That's consistent with what I see. However, my intension is to find mouse pointer position when the label gets the focus but without moving the mouse (sorry I didn't express that clearly) - I am trying to let the user compare two datasets which are plotted as heatmaps in labels, and when the user uses Ctrl+Tab to switch between those two labels (sub windows in QMdiArea), the value under the mouse should be shown in tooltips, if it is possible to get the mouse pointer position without moving mouse.

Comment: You could use static function `QCursor::pos()` to get current cursor position if widget gets focus. After that get global position of your label widget upper left corner using `mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0))` and lower right corner using `mapToGlobal(QPoint(width(), height()))`. Finally check if cursor position is inside your label widgets rectangle and run an action (e.g. show tooltip).

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. Could you possibly summarize what you said as an answer? That way, I can accept it as the answer, and it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if mouse cursor is on custom widget derived from `QLabel` at time when it gets focus just override `focusInEvent()` and handle mouse cursor position check there.

**MyLabel.h**

```
class MyLabel: public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyLabel();

protected:
    virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event) override;
};
```

**MyLabel.cpp**

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent)
{
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
}

MyLabel::~MyLabel()
{
}

void MyLabel::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    if (event) {
        const QPoint cursorPos = QCursor::pos();
        if (rect().contains(mapFromGlobal(cursorPos))) {
            // TODO: Add desired action
        }
        QLabel::focusInEvent(event);
    }
}
```